# Highlight specific word in a pdf document using itext7

Tags: java, itext7

I want to create a pdf report in which some of the text alone is need to be highlighted while generating report.

my current code

```
private static Text returnCorrectColor(String letter,String htext, PdfFont helveticaFont, PdfFont helveticaBoldFont) {
    ArrayList<String>htextaslist = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(htext.trim().split("\\r?\\n")));
    String v=StringUtils.normalizeSpace( htext.trim());

    Boolean flag=false;
    try {
        for (int i=0;i<htextaslist.size();i++) {
            System.out.println("entire linr"+letter);
            System.out.println("htext"+htextaslist.get(i));
            if (letter.trim().contains(htextaslist.get(i).trim())) {
                System.out.println("boolran"+"0inside");
                flag=true;
                if(flag)
                {
                    break;
                }
            } 
            else {
                flag=false;
            }

        }
    } catch (PatternSyntaxException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        flag=true;
    }
    if(flag) {
        return new Text(letter)
                 .setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN)
                 .setFontColor(Color.BLACK)
                 .setFont(helveticaBoldFont);
    } else {
        return new Text(String.valueOf(letter))
              .setFontColor(Color.BLACK)
              .setFont(helveticaFont);
    
    }           
}
```

with this i'm able to highlight the entire line but what i need is to highlight a specific text that is "htext" only to be highlighted in a line.

And i don't hardcode the data in paragraph
i call this method inside a for loop like

```
outputaslist = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(output.split("\\r?\\n")));
for (int s = 0; s < outputaslist.size(); s++) {     
    paragraph.add(returnCorrectColor(outputaslist.get(s),testcaselist.get(i).getHtext(), helveticaFont, helveticaBoldFont));
    paragraph.add("\n");
}
```

my current ouput is like the above one but i expect the one below
[image: current output]

[image: Expected output]

Is there any way to do this?

one of my sample input

```
outputActive Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       
 PID/Program name    
 tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
1185/systemd-resolv 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1441/cupsd          
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1780/nginx: master  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:35373         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1616/containerd     
tcp        0      0 10.10.100.242:51938     13.33.60.102:443        TIME_WAIT   -                   
 tcp        0      0 10.10.100.242:52762     34.210.242.116:443      ESTABLISHED 6994/firefox
```

I would like to highlight only listen in the output

Comment: You need to return several `Text` elements, some of them would be colored with green background color and some will remain in their default mode. Right now it's not obvious how to reproduce your problem since you did not provide the input you feed into your code

Comment: @AlexeySubach updatedmy post. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to the party, but I had a similar issue,

To do this you have to find the locations of your words, then highlight those words.

```
    public static List<IPdfTextLocation> PdfFindKeywordLocations(PdfDocument pdfDocument, Keyword keyword, int pageNumber)
    {
        string cleanKeyword = DataFormatHelper.ReplaceStringText(keyword.Name, new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {"[ ]", @"\W"}
        });

        Regex regex = new Regex(cleanKeyword, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        RegexBasedLocationExtractionStrategy extractionStrategy = new RegexBasedLocationExtractionStrategy(regex);

        PdfCanvasProcessor parser = new PdfCanvasProcessor(extractionStrategy);

        parser.ProcessPageContent(pdfDocument.GetPage(pageNumber));

        return extractionStrategy.GetResultantLocations().ToList();
    }

    private static void PdfHighlightLocations(PdfDocument pdfDocument, IEnumerable<IPdfTextLocation> locations, int pageNumber)
    {
        PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(pdfDocument.GetPage(pageNumber).NewContentStreamBefore(), pdfDocument.GetPage(pageNumber).GetResources(), pdfDocument);

        foreach (var l in locations)
        {
            pdfCanvas.SaveState().SetFillColor(ColorConstants.GREEN).Rectangle(l.GetRectangle().GetX(), l.GetRectangle().GetY(), l.GetRectangle().GetWidth(), l.GetRectangle().GetHeight()).Fill().RestoreState();
        }
    }
```